# Y800 image format(s) available in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-formats

What is possible image format of Y800 which is available in OpenCV? is it always referred to GRAY? Any other options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Y800 is a monochrome format - what could it be except GRAY? Can you reword your question if I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, it's monochrome, but is it the same as GRAY defined in OpenCV?

Comment: Ok, according to this - http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php - `Y800` is the same as `GREY` (not GRAY) and maybe also the same as `Y8`.

Comment: If you said so, that means for the following line `cv::cvtColor(frame, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);`, that means gray_image that is meant to be converted to gray format is not the same as Y800. Am I right, according to your answer?

Comment: That is correct (as I understand things) - `CV_BGR2GRAY` gives a greyscale image format, while `Y800` is a FOURCC video codec. They are not the same, but they are both greyscale.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142837/what-image-formats-other-than-y800-does-zbarimageimage-accept

Answer (score 0):

Eight years later, I stumbled upon this question. I want to add an answer with regard to OpenCV 4.2.0.

For *videos*, this version features an ffmpeg backend which natively understands the FOURCC identifier "Y800". Confusingly, it does not take one-channel grayscale (`CV_8UC1`) frames, but the usual OpenCV three-channel BGR (`CV_8UC3`):

```
cv::VideoWriter vw("y8.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('Y', '8', '0', '0'), 60, frame.size());
vw.write(frame); // note: frame must be 8UC3!
```

OpenCV supports the grayscale mode in number of *image* file formats, including, but not limited to PGM, PNG and JPEG.

```
cv::imwrite("gray.pgm", image);
```