# What image formats other than "Y800" does zbar::Image::Image() accept?

Tags: c++, zbar

The documentation for [zbar::Image::Image()](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/api/classzbar_1_1Image.html#5134e2e814da0d0070ef165898980848) doesn't say anything about the accepted image formats:

> zbar::Image::Image    (   unsigned    width = 0, unsigned     height = 0, const
> std::string &     format = "", const void *   data = NULL, unsigned long
> length = 0    )         [inline] constructor.
>
> create a new Image with the specified parameters

Since `format` is a string, not an enum, I can't know the possible values. The only value I know is `Y800` from the [scan_image.cpp](https://github.com/herbyme/zbar/blob/master/examples/scan_image.cpp) sample that comes with zbar:

```
Image image(width, height, "Y800", raw, width * height);
```

Are there any other possible values? Also does it matter if I've compiled it without ImageMagick support (I passed `--without-imagemagick` to `./configure`)?

**Edit:** I found another possible format mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892668/492336) to another question:

> By the Way : zbar Accepts ["GREY" format too](https://github.com/herbyme/zbar/blob/068c810f75994b61ab9edc689650d09a0fc78bf9/zbar/convert.c#L81)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Digging through the library code, the supported fourcc formats depend on what video capture api you need to use:

- zbar/video/v4l1.c, Video4Linux, v4l1_formats[] lists GREY, HI24 (HI240), RGBP (RGB565), BGR3 (RGB24), BGR4 (RGB32), RGBO (RGB555), YUY2 (YUV422), YUYV, UYVY, Y41P (YUV411), 422P (YUV422P), 411P (YUV411P), YU12 (YUV420P), YUV9 (YUV410P).
- zbar/video/vfw.c, Video for Windows, vfw_formats[] lists I420, YV12, NV12, UYVY, YUY2, BGR3, BGR4, YVU9, GREY, Y800, JPEG.

Surely more than you'd like to see, it is also going to depend on what the camera can supply.  You'll no doubt have to make this a config setting.